# Expectation of dirac measure of a function

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Suppose $\pi(dx)$ is a measure, $\phi$ is a deterministic function and $\delta_{\phi(x)}(A)$ is the dirac measure. The dirac measure can be considered a measurable function (I think? Should be a kernel) for a fixed set $A$. What does the expectation of $\delta_{\phi(\cdot)}(A)$ becomes with respect to $\pi$?
$$
\int \delta_{\phi(x)}(A)\,\, \pi(dx) = \int_A\pi(d\phi(x)) \qquad ???
$$

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac measure is :
$$\delta_{\phi(x)}(A) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1 & \text{if } \phi(x) \in A \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array}\right. = \chi_{\phi^{-1}(A)}(x)$$

with $\chi$ the indicator function.

Therefore,
$$\int \delta_{\phi(x)}(A) \pi(\text{d}x) = \int \chi_{\phi^{-1}(A)}(x) \pi(\text{d}x) = \pi\circ\phi^{-1}(A)$$

Comment: Amazing, thank you! So basically this new measure is the pushforward $\phi_*\pi$?